# Block main thread until python background thread finishes side-task

Tags: python, multithreading, synchronization

I have a threaded python application with a long-running mainloop in the background thread. This background mainloop is actually a call to [pyglet.app.run()](http://pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.app-module.html), which drives a GUI window and also can be configured to call other code periodically. I need a `do_stuff(duration)` function to be called at will from the main thread to trigger an animation in the GUI, wait for the animation to stop, and then return. The actual animation must be done in the background thread because the GUI library can't handle being driven by separate threads.

I believe I need to do something like this:

```
import threading

class StuffDoer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.max_n_times = 0
        self.total_n_times = 0
        self.paused_ev = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        # this part is outside of my control
        while True:
            self._do_stuff()
            # do other stuff

    def _do_stuff(self):
        # this part is under my control
        if self.paused_ev.is_set():
            if self.max_n_times > self.total_n_times:
                self.paused_ev.clear()
        else:
            if self.total_n_times >= self.max_n_times:
                self.paused_ev.set()
        if not self.paused_ev.is_set():
            # do stuff that must execute in the background thread
            self.total_n_times += 1

sd = StuffDoer()
sd.start()

def do_stuff(n_times):
    sd.max_n_times += n_times
    sd.paused_ev.wait_for_clear()   # wait_for_clear() does not exist
    sd.paused_ev.wait()
    assert (sd.total_n_times == sd.max_n_times)
```

EDIT: use `max_n_times` instead of `stop_time` to clarify why `Thread.join(duration)` won't do the trick.

From the documentation for [threading.Event](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#event-objects):

> wait([timeout])
>
> Block until the internal flag is true.
>   If the internal flag is true on entry,
>   return immediately. Otherwise, block
>   until another thread calls set() to
>   set the flag to true, or until the
>   optional timeout occurs.

I've found I can get the behavior I'm looking for if I have a pair of events, `paused_ev` and `not_paused_ev`, and use `not_paused_ev.wait()`. I could almost just use `Thread.join(duration)`, except it needs to only return precisely when the background thread *actually* registers that the time is up. Is there some other synchronization object or other strategy I should be using instead?

I'd also be open to arguments that I'm approaching this whole thing the wrong way, provided they're good arguments.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're attempting to accomplish?  You want something to happen when the main thread terminates?  Or you want something to happen for a specific length of time while the main thread runs?  Or the main thread needs to signal another thread?  What is your goal?

Comment: Sorry, yes, added more clarification. I don't want to give too overwhelmingly much detail about the GUI, because my question is mostly about the threading and blocking.

Comment: I found and fixed a very significant problem in my question (terribly sorry, it's hard to test code that hasn't been written). What I need to be waiting for is a rising edge of `paused_ev`, and the way it was written it was waiting for a _rising_ edge.

Comment: I was looking at the `threading` module documentation again, and I think `threading.Condition` is probably what I need. I was confused by the fact that apparently more than one thread can `acquire()` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a Queue similar to what @wberry suggested, and making use of `Queue.task_done` and `Queue.wait`:

```
import Queue
import threading

class StuffDoer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.setDaemon(True)
        self.max_n_times = 0
        self.total_n_times = 0
        self.do_queue = Queue.Queue()

    def run(self):
        # this part is outside of my control
        while True:
            self._do_stuff()
            # do other stuff

    def _do_stuff(self):
        # this part is under my control
        if self.total_n_times >= self.max_n_times:
            try:
                self.max_n_times += self.do_queue.get(block=False)
            except Queue.Empty, e:
                pass
        if self.max_n_times > self.total_n_times:
            # do stuff that must execute in the background thread
            self.total_n_times += 1
            if self.total_n_times >= self.max_n_times:
                self.do_queue.task_done()

sd = StuffDoer()
sd.start()

def do_stuff(n_times):
    sd.do_queue.put(n_times)
    sd.do_queue.join()
    assert (sd.total_n_times == sd.max_n_times)
```

Answer (score 3):

Hoping I get some revision or additional info from my comment, but I'm kind of wondering if you're not overworking things by subclassing Thread.  You can do things like this:

```
class MyWorker(object):
  def __init__(self):
    t = Thread(target = self._do_work, name "Worker Owned Thread")

    t.daemon = True

    t.start()

  def _do_work(self):
    While True:
      # Something going on here, forever if necessary.  This thread
      # will go away if the other non-daemon threads terminate, possibly
      # raising an exception depending this function's body.
```

I find this makes more sense when the method you want to run is something that is more appropriately a member function of some other class than it would be to as the run method on the thread.  Additionally, this saves you from having to encapsulate a bunch of business logic inside of a Thread. All IMO, of course.

Comment: I think this wouldn't be an option for me because the work has to happen in a specific, already-running thread that's doing other work.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your GUI animation thread is using a spin-lock in its `while True` loop.  This can be prevented using thread-safe queues.  Based on my reading of your question, this approach would be functionally equivalent and efficient.

I'm omitting some details of your code above which would not change.  I'm also assuming here that the run() method which you do not control uses the self.stop_time value to do its work; otherwise there is no need for a threadsafe queue.

```js
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Event

class StuffDoer:
  def __init__(self, inq, ready):
    self.inq = inq
    self.ready = ready
  def _do_stuff(self):
    self.ready.set()
    self.stop_time = self.inq.get()

GUIqueue = Queue()
control = Event()

sd = StuffDoer(GUIqueue, control)

def do_stuff(duration):
  control.clear()
  GUIqueue.put(time.time() + duration)
  control.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

I made solution based on [@g.d.d.c](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351031/g-d-d-c) [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6605600/1105597) for this question. There is my code:

```
threads = []
# initializing aux thread(s) in the main thread ...
t = threading.Thread(target=ThreadF, args=(...))
#t.setDaemon(True) # I'm not sure does it really needed
t.start()
threads.append(t.ident)

# Block main thread
while filter(lambda thread: thread.ident in threads, threading.enumerate()):
    time.sleep(10)
```

Also, you can use `Thread.join` to block the main thread - it is better way.